# ReactJs | Set Button Visbility On State Change

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I am using material UI button in my react application.
Button is not getting disappeared when I am changing the state.
Below is my code for it -

```
function MainPage() {
    const state = useSelector(state => state.loginDetails.state)

    const [visibilitySetting, setVisibility] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(state.loginType)
      if(state.loginType=="google")
      {
          setVisibility(false)
      }
    }, [])   
    

    return (
      <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
        <Button color="primary" variant="contained" style={{display:visibilitySetting}}   >
          Group
        </Button>
)
```

I have made sure from code `state.loginType` is `google`.

I also tried on display=none ; but effect didnt took place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UseEffect only runs once. For it to run again when the state changes, you need to add a dependency in the dependency array in useEffect.

Try this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
      console.log(state.loginType)
      if(state.loginType=="google")
      {
          setVisibility(false)
      }
    }, [state.loginType])
```

And the button component as (By conditional rendering) :

```
{visibilitySetting &&<Button color="primary" variant="contained">
          Group
        </Button>}
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: This is working perfect , no need of [state.loginType] in useeffect , as logintype is setting only once upon page load. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You are only setting `true` and `false` to `display` property. You should check condition as well

`<Button ... style={{display: visibilitySetting ? 'block' : 'none'}}>`

Comment: Yeah , this should also work , but as I mentioned in the last line of my problem statement , somehow this was also not working.. But thanks for answer , this also may help someone.